# Navigation menu not quite working in IE7

Tags: css, wordpress, html, internet-explorer

I'm having issues with the navigation menu in my website. It works great in every browser and version except IE 7 and was wondering if someone could diagnose what might be wrong.

My CSS

```
nav {
    background: url(../images/links-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    width: 593px;
    height:60px;
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #991318;
    border-right: 1px solid #991318;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #991318;
    border-left: none;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 40px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #991318;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'MEgalopolisExtraRegular', Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
nav li a:hover, nav li .selected {
    color: #352E24;
}
```

My HTML

```
<nav id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

Anyone know what might be causing this> Is my CSS off somewhere?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

And I don't appreciate people who whine about coding for IE 7. I'm coding for it, not you, so if you don't have anything supportive to say, don't say it at all.

Comment: For starters, I would clear your floated `<li>`s with a `<br clear="all" />` just before the closing `</div>` (.menu-main-nav-menu-container). I don't think that's what's breaking it, but IE is messy if you don't clear your floats.

Comment: I think I may see the problem... try removing the reference to your reset stylesheet (reset.css) in `http://safetyspeakers.ca/wp-content/themes/SafetySpeakersTheme/style.css` and let me know what that does. Your index-final.html does not appear to have this reference.

Comment: nevvvermind... I see now they are condensed in your single staging CSS file.

Answer (score -1):

IE 7 does not understand the nav element, you need to use a ul instead